# How to pass Data from one template to another template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

at first, I want to say that I am new at programing and also at AngularJS so please be a little forgiving.

My Problem is a little complex but i try to explain it as good as i can. At first i want to tell you what im actully doing.
I have to expand the local "Intrant" from my company and now i try to integrate an overview about the forms which are used by the employeers.
I have differnt groups and childgroups which are already implemented and shown on the first template. My problem is that i can not access to the data after i opend a new template which is made to show the forms which are a part of the childgroups.
Here you can see my first template, this shows all upper groups:

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
  <h1 class="h3 nomargin">Formulare</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <ng-repeat ng-repeat="objFormGroup in arrFormGroups">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            <name-form-group data-group="objFormGroup"></name-form-group>
        </div>
    </ng-repeat>
</div>
```

The "objFromGroup" is filled in the "module.js" and the data is comming out of a REST-Service which is hosted local on my computer. 
Also there is an dropdown menü which is opened throgh the "< name-from-group >"and this refers to another template:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
            <button id="bdd" class="dropbtn" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled"><a href="#"><font color="#fff">{{group.name}}<span class="caret"></span></font></a></button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="childGroup in group.ChildGroups">
                    <a href="app/templates/wforms/over_view_forms.html">{{childGroup.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br>    <br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is working. But now i want to open the third template (over_view_froms) to show the forms which are part of the childgroup the user clicked on. But when i try to display the forms by using the data which is comming out of the REST-Service it is not working. I also can not access to the data i used befor like {{childGroups.name}} on this template.
Here you can see the last template where the forms should be display:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
    <caption>{{childGroup.name}}</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Formular</th>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Größe</th>
        <th>Stand</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{group.childGroup.Formulare.name}}</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

module.js:

```
strehlowIntranet
    .config(['$stateProvider', 'strehlowConfigProvider', function ($stateProvider, strehlowConfigProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.formgroups', {
                url: '/formgroups',
                label: 'Formulare',
                template_icon: 'fa fa-file-pdf-o',
                resolve: {
                    objFormGroups: ['FormsService', function (FormsService) {
                        return FormsService.getFormGroups();
                    }]
                },
                views: {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/templates/wforms/over_view.html',
                        controller: ['$scope', 'objFormGroups', function ($scope, objFormGroups) {
                            $scope.arrFormGroups = objFormGroups;
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
       $stateProvider
            .state('app.groupdetail',{
                url: '/groupdetail',
                resolve: {
                    objSingleGroup: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                        return $stateParams.group;
                    }]
                },
                views: {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/templates/wforms/over_view_forms.html',
                        controller: ['$scope', 'objSingleGroup', function ($scope, objSingleGroup) {
                           $scope.objGroup = objSingleGroup;
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
    }]);
```

So my question is how can i display the data on this template.

Thanks to everyone who trys to help me. (:

Comment: You cant access one-page data to other, both are independent there is no relation between both the pages. over_view_forms.html is inside same application?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes it is.

Comment: What I mean to say is, Have you created the route for that? Does not look like the route.

Comment: @RahulSharma i do not really know what u mean, maybe my module.js can help to see if i have some?

Comment: Share that, It does not look like single page application because your over_view_forms.html looks like the independent page.

Comment: the files you posted is not enough to debug the case, kindly post your js files and routes files and try to use any playground like jsfiddle or codepen or even stackoverflow snippets

Comment: i think you are right,at the moment it is not a single page application, when the user clicks on a child group it opens it on another page but the goal is different. I want the page to be within the same application. i will add the mudule.js